# bat - файл для переименовівания *.doc - файлов в *.txt

Tags: cmd

Здравствуйте. Нужен bat - ник для задания описаного в заголовке.
Он должен переименовывать файлы находящиеся в папке Network. Делал так:

```
С:\Documents and Settings\Admin>md "С:\Documents and Settings\Network\New"
С:\Documents and Settings\Admin>copy con "С:\Documents and Settings\Network\New\1.doc"
С:\Documents and Settings\Admin>copy con "С:\Documents and Settings\Network\New\2.doc"
С:\Documents and Settings\Admin>copy con "С:\Documents and Settings\Network\New\3.doc"

С:\Documents and Settings\Admin>copy con txt_maker.bat
@echo off
for /r "С:\Documents and Settings\Network" %%f in (*.doc?) do ren "%%f" "%%f.txt"
^Z
```

Comment: ren C:\SomePath\\*.doc C:\SomePath\\*.txt вас не устроит?

Comment: А почему вы пишете `copy con`? Какая логика?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, нужно с использованием for

Comment: @VladD, один из спосбов создать файл, а почему бы и нет?

Comment: @MuscledBoy: А откуда взялось требование делать через for? Одиночный `ren` прекрасно справляется.

Comment: @VladD, так стоит задание

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for /R %%x in (*.doc) do ren "%%x" *.txt
```

Запуск bat-файла с таким содержимым в каталоге рекурсивно переименует doc в txt в этом каталоге и ниже.
Если нужно только в отдельном каталоге, это делается через

```
ren C:\SomePath\*.doc C:\SomePath\*.txt
```

Comment: спасибо помогло. Могу ли еще просить Вас о помощи? Нужно чтобы Вы меня исправили, если я не правильно что -то понял.

Comment: почему когда мы создаем параметр кавычек не пишем, а потом ставим в перечне команд?

Comment: @MuscledBoy не знаю, таков синтаксис, вероятно.